# Does NSDictionary always give output surrounded by double quotes?

Tags: iphone

This is my code:

```
//elementsValues is type of NSDictionary. currentElementValue is type of NSString.
//resultArray is type of NSArray.
//elementName = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SignOnResult"];

[self.elementsValues setObject:self.currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
[self.resultArray addObject:self.elementsValues];
NSLog(@"%@",[resultArray valueForKey:@"SignOnResult"]);
```

The output i get is printed in between " ". So does NSDictionary give output always in " " ?
I dont want the string in " ".

Comment: You are doing wrong, resultArray is an array and you need to fetch NSDictionary from array using objectAtIndex method of array

Comment: Most likely that the string you are getting from XML is `@" "` so you will have to handle it there. That said, the `NSLog` statement must be logging a single element array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong for calling `valueForKey:` with `resultArray` instance it will return you the empty `NSArray`,

```
NSLog(@"%@",[resultArray valueForKey:@"SignOnResult"]); // wrong statement
```

Try to change as

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[resultArray objectAtIndex:dictionaryIndex] valueForKey:@"SignOnResult"]);
```

Here `dictionaryIndex` is the integer type and point the valid index and dictionary object in your `resultArray` .

Comment: You can call [`valueForKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/valueForKey:).

Comment: @Deepak: I am calling the `valueForKey:` on the `dictionary` instance return by `[resultArray objectAtIndex:dictionaryIndex]`

Comment: I meant `valueForKey:` is a valid message to `NSArray`. The link takes you to the `NSArray` reference. It will call `valueForKey:` on all the members and returns an array.

Comment: @Deepak : thanks for info. i just come to know about `valueForKey:` method in `NSArray` today but i feel one first need to store the value through `setValue:` then only `valueForKey:` can be used for retrieval, plz correct me if i am wrong .

Comment: Even `setValue:forKey:` will invoke it on each of the objects something like `makeObjectsPerformSelector:`. However it is not necessary for `setValue:forKey:` to be done before doing `valueForKey:` as the dictionaries have the values. Remember KVC.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.resultArray objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"%@",dictionary);
```